# Recreate DCE'd method for use with DLL injection

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dll-injection

I'm writing a mod for a game using DLL injection (specifically [Unity Doorstop](https://github.com/NeighTools/UnityDoorstop)). My mod uses an external package not specifically meant for DLL injection, in this case it's [MoonSharp](https://www.moonsharp.org/).

I have a problem where the game's `System.dll` file seems to have been rid of the setter for `System.Collection.Generic.LinkedListNode.Value`, as inspecting the DLL in ILSpy shows only a getter. I suspect Dead Code Elimination since every spec I've been able to read (and my own inspection of my system's `System.dll`) shows that a setter exists. MoonSharp's code unfortunately makes use of this setter, which throws a `MethodNotFound` exception on the call site. I've been able to replicate this outside of MoonSharp so I know it's not the lib's fault.

I haven't been able to replace the game's `System.dll` file successfully since my project only seems to output a reference assembly with no function bodies. I'm not terribly familiar with C# in general, so my question is as follows: is there a way around this situation? My non-educated guesses are:

- defining the setter out-of-source, but this sounds impossible since LinkedListNode is sealed and its `item` member (which `Value` accesses) is marked internal.
- rewriting `LinkedListNode` entirely and somehow making everything use that instead of `System.Collection.Generic.LinkedListNode`

Any ideas?